# Django models.py I want a function go to a variable

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I want the def remain and the result of it to go to the field d_remain but whatever I use the function  it doesn't show anything, it shows only negative numbers, this is my code, this is the base code give me a way to make it happen thank you.

```
class sub(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, primary_key = True, editable = False)
    provider = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    tier = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    date_started = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    date_end = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, )
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    d_remain = models.IntegerField()#I want the value of def remain go to this filed 
    def remain(self):
        today = date.today()
        remaining_days = (self.date_end - today).days
        return(remaining_days)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('sub-detail', kwargs={'pk':self.id})
```

Comment: Don't store fully functional depdencies in a database.

Comment: What is preventing you from assigning to the variable from the inside the function?  How have you even *tried* to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't store fully functional dependencies in a database. Indeed, if something fully depends on a (set of) column(s), it makes no sense to store it as an extra column. At best it will require extra storage, but very likely it also becomes a lot harder to keep the item in sync, since now for each update of the columns, you need to update the dependent column as well.

In this specific case, each day you would have to update the number of remaining days. This would require running a daily query, that can fail as well, and if the `date_end` is modified, you should always update the `d_remaining` columns, which will of course easily result into data inconsistencies.

You can define a property that will calculate the number of remaining days when necessary:

```
from django.conf import settings


class Sub(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, primary_key=True, editable=False)
    provider = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    tier = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    date_started = models.DateField()
    date_end = models.DateField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    # no d_remain

    @property
    def remain(self):
        return (self.date_end - date.today()).days

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('sub-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

and for the queries, we can query with:

```
Sub.objects.filter(date_end__lte=date.today() - timedelta(days=5))
```

to get the `Sub`s that end within *five* days.

---

> **Note**: Models in Django are written in *PascalCase*, not *snake_case*,
> so you might want to rename the model from <s>`sub`</s> to `Sub`.

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

Comment: Thank you for the specified answer, way i want to make extra storage for it, so I can use django-celery-beat package. to give it the value, then it will see the d_remain and then if it's more than 3 it will do nothing, else if it's less than 3 days it will send an email, BTW I'm no expert just a beginner in Django don't expect much from me, Again Thank you

Comment: @&FK-_Q: but it is a *very* bad idea: it takes extra storage, more queries, makes querying less efficient, results larger, so it blows up memory, and introduces data duplications and therefore eventually data corruption. The data is already there by the `end_date`, so it makes no sense to store the number of remaining days explicitly as an extra column: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/database-administration-sql-server/five-simple-database-design-errors-you-should-avoid/ and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_normal_form

Comment: Thank you so much, I feel so dumb Right now, Now I realize what are you trying to say.